# How to dynamically increase the height of only one section in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview

I'm trying to have a dynamic height for my screen that adjusts according to the length of the content. I have two sections, first of which has a set height, and the second of which is supposed to increase/decrease in its height depending on the content.

How to have set a minimum set height for Section 2 and still be dynamic if necessary?

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        // section 1
    <View>
    <View style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
        // section 2
    </View>
</ScrollView>
```

I tried the `flowGrow` approach, but doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the height of a view to 100, just do

```
<View style={{height:100}}>
```

If you don`t set anything, View component will grow with its content. So do:

```
<View>
```

For your whole example:

```
<ScrollView>
    <View style={{ height: 100 }}>
        // section 1
    <View>
    <View>
        // section 2
    </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you. What if I wanted to have a minimum height for Section 2 and increase in height if necessary?

Comment: use `style={{minHeight:100}}` instead